# Logging nginx to syslog on CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

Fresh install of CentOS 7 and nginx 1.6.3.  Per [the official documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/) I set the access_log directive to forward via syslog to a remote server in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
#access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log   main;
access_log syslog:server=[10.1.2.3],facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=info;
```

When I restart (or start) nginx with that change, I get the following error:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status nginx.service
(...)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/syslog:server=[10.1.2.3],facility=local7,tag=nginx,severity=info" failed (13: Permission denied)
(...)
```

It's like the service doesn't know how to parse its own config file correctly, as if the IP and options are part of a file it's trying to read from.  Anyone get this working, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have old nginx.

`Logging to syslog is available since version 1.7.1. As part of our commercial subscription logging to syslog is available since version 1.5.3.`

from documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html

Comment: Well that would explain that.  That worked, thanks!  Another note is that the square brackets are only for IPv6... you can safely omit them for IPv4 addresses.